# what will happen if I ufw deny port 22

Tags: ssh, ufw

What will happen if I accidently `# ufw deny 22` ?

Will I be logged out immediately and never be able to access the server via ssh again? If so, is there any other way to revert the access?

`ssh` is setup on default port and I have root access to the server.

Comment: I would expect it to let me continue that session, but not allow any new connections. I don't know much about how it works, though.